# Best Kentico Way to Host Multiple 404 pages in the Content Tree

Tags: http-status-code-404, kentico

I'm looking for the best (or a very good) "Kentico way" to accomplish having multiple 404 Not Found pages inside the content tree, each for a different area of the content tree.

For example, given the following hypothetical content tree structure with blog items and partner profiles,

```
% Root Master
|__ Home
|__ Blog ._ Blog Item A 
         |_ Blog Item B
         |_ Blog Item C
         |_ 404 Page for Blogs
|__ Policy
|__ Partners ._ Partner Profile A
             |_ Partner Profile B
             |_ Partner Profile C
             |_ 404 Page for Partners
|_ Site 404 Page
```

I'm looking for the following behaviour:

- if the user visits a Blog Item D which does not exist, I want to 404 Page for Blogs to be displayed.
- likewise if the user visits a Partner Profile D which does not exist,I want the 404 Page for Partners to show.
- If any other page is Not found in the site then the Site 404 Page should be shown, as per normal, through Kentico setting for this.

I'm hesitant to dip down into only using ASP.NET configuration for this because I want to maintain the solution inside Kentico and without recycling the website's application pool when adding new 404 pages.

My immediate thought is to create a custom web part that I can drop onto the Site's global 404 Page Template (the default place for every 404).  This web part would use the Error Path (ala querystring value aspxerrorpath=) to  see the path that was not found and then check to see if it contains the word "blogs" or "partners" and redirect the browser to the appropriate sub-404-page respectively. Or, is there an even simpler approach -- maybe using page aliases and/or macros -- while keeping the solution inside Kentico?

I'm using Kentico 9 & 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is a good way to handle this within Kentico.  The best way is most likely going to be adding `<location>` elements in your master web.config and setting those paths and 404 pages in there.

Another might be to manage it via a webpart as you mentioned.  But I might take it one step further and make a module out of it so your webpart could perform a lookup based on the referring URL or error page in question and do any custom displaying or redirecting based on the lookup values it matches.

Comment: Thank you Brenden for the info. This makes sense. I hadn't thought about the module strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bit unnatural for web site to have multiple 404. I think what you describing  is the Kentico way. On this one common 404 page you can drop multiple static HTML web parts and make them enable based on ErrorPath, if none of ErrorPath are matched you have a generic static HTML web part to handle common case.
P.S. Technically you can have specific web.config per folder in IIS and try to play around with that, but Kentico Tree is purely virtual, so what you describing is pretty much the Kentico way.

Comment: Thank you Shof for confirming. You're right that there's no real way for me to use .net configuration effectively because the tree is virtual.